# How to make your page embeddable as an iframe in facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe

I am trying to create a website in which when a Facebook user share the page url in facebook it should get embedded as an iframe rather than a link. How can i do this?

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about a page tab? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

Comment: Nope. I am talking about posts. When you share a link